# Lebesgue inner measure

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking for a simple proof of well-definedness of Lebesgue inner measure.
Though I've somehow proven it, it must be mistake, and even if it is a right proof, it's too long.
Therefore, if someone knows a simple proof, please teach me.

Definitions of Lebesgue outer measure and inner measure is as follows :

$~~~~~~~~~~m^*(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty |I_k|\,\middle|\,E\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k,~\text{each }I_k\text{ is interval}\right\},$

$~~~~~~~~~~m_*(E)=|I|-m^*(I-E)~~(E\subset I,~I\text{ is interval}). $